# PlayFramework 2.4.6 error 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: playframework, netty, multipartform-data, playframework-2.4

I am using PlayFramework 2.4.6, trying to upload a multipart file (size 18M) and the server returns the following error:

```
For request 'POST /api/myEndpoint' [Request Entity Too Large]
```

I have looked around and tried the following with out success:

1. play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=2000000K
2. parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength=1024000K
3. play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=2000000K
4. Action.async(parse.anyContent(Some(1024*200L)))

And none of them solves the problem.

Here is the Stacktrace as well:

> ```
> 14:57:33.128 [New I/O worker #2] [error] -     p.c.server.netty.RequestBodyHandler - Exception caught in RequestBodyHandler
> java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.setInterestOps(AbstractNioWorker.java:506) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker$1.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:455) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper.run(ChannelRunnableWrapper.java:40) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
> ```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Solved the problem with this:

```
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer = 100MB

parsers.anyContent.maxLength = 100MB
```

Comment: @gleeb, could you please explain where to put these options in the application.conf ifle? I put these options at the end of application.conf, but it doesn't work.

Comment: application.conf

Comment: Relevant section in Java Play 2.8.* (if anybody upgraded and found this like me) is https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length

Answer (score 28):

I was having the same problem sending a large form and `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=4MB` solved it.

Comment: I had both of the options from Gleeb's answer and yet no help. This one helped me.

Answer (score 20):

See this documentation about the memory and disk buffers Play uses:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length

> Text based body parsers (such as text, json, xml or formUrlEncoded) use a max content length because they have to load all the content into memory. By default, the maximum content length that they will parse is **100KB**. It can be overridden by specifying the `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer` property in application.conf:
>
> `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=128K`
>
> For parsers that buffer content on disk, such as the raw parser or multipart/form-data, the maximum content length is specified using the `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer` property, it defaults to **10MB**. The multipart/form-data parser also enforces the text max length property for the aggregate of the data fields.

So, since you're trying to uploading a multipart file, you'll need to increase the `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer` to something >18MB.

So, adding this to your application.conf should fix it:

```
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=100MB
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing issue with Play Framework 2.6.x see documentation at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaBodyParsers

> Max content length Text based body parsers (such as text, json, xml or
>   formUrlEncoded) use a max content length because they have to load all
>   the content into memory. By default, the maximum content length that
>   they will parse is 100KB. It can be overridden by specifying the
>   play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer property in application.conf:

add following in application.conf:

```
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer = 5MB
```

Comment: This answer seems to reiterate the same solution as previous ones. If you feel you have something to add, please leave it as a comment on the original answer. Alternatively if you have a different solution, please explain why it's different (and possibly better).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using an `AnyContent` Parser. I changed the `controller` definition to following to make my code work

```
def newQuestion = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.maxLength(1024 * 1024, parse.anyContent)(ActorMaterializer()(ActorSystem("MyApplication")))){

  implicit request => {
      println("got request with body:" + request.body)
      val anyBodyErrors: Either[MaxSizeExceeded, AnyContent] = request.body
      anyBodyErrors match {
        case Left(size) => {
          Future {
            EntityTooLarge(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.entityTooLarge")(langs.availables(0)))))
          }
        }
        case Right(body) => {

          //val body:AnyContent = request.body
          val jsonBodyOption = body.asJson
...
}
}
```